# How can I merge unallocated partition with an extended partition?

Tags: linux, partition

I need to combine the unallocated space on my computer into one partition. Originally I had Windows in the other partition but I recently deleted it because I no longer use it and I only ever use Linux. I use GParted Partition Editor to try and fix it but the partition I want to expand is the one that is in use thus it won't let me resize or move it. I want to know if there is a way to fix this without having to use a live CD or usb? This is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

If there's no way to do it without using a live CD then I guess I just have to  do it, but I really don't want to have to buy anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize a partition if it's mounted, see this link to the Ubuntu documentation for a good guide to resizing partitions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition

The easiest thing to do would be to use a live CD but you shouldn't have to buy anything. If you've got the disk or USB stick you orginally installed Ubuntu from you can use this, follow the instructions in the link:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

The live version of Ubuntu has GParted included. You can now use to manipulate your hard drive as you wish.

As alternative suggestions, if you have a spare disc or USB stick you could Google for GParted or Knoppix live CDs, both are free.